# Is it possible to get a Facebook event name by its URL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get a Facebook event name by its URL? In the API/developers or through their graph it isn't clear if this is possible. I'm trying to implement a widget in my site where the user inputs certain event URL and then the widget parses the URL and gives the event name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last part of an event URL is the event ID:

```
https://www.facebook.com/events/137072909798458/
```

You could just [parse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) the URL to get the ID and use it with Graph:

```
graph.facebook.com/137072909798458/
```